# Jquery 1.7 and IE 8 memory leakage

Tags: jquery, memory-leaks

I have a script which runs on every page on an intranet, which adds events, sets size, length for input fields based on a class (this allows for different configurations between comapnies).

However, I've noticed that I'm getting memory leakage.

My code for adding the events is :

```
        $("input.PartNo" ).addClass("font8_input").attr({maxlength: '20',size:'20'})
        .bind('focus',function(event){javascript:fncAjaxClear();$(this).addClass("input_focus");})
        .bind('blur',function(event){if (typeof fncPartBlur === "function") fncPartBlur(''+$(this).attr("id")+'');$(this).removeClass("input_focus input_error");})
        .bind('keyup',function(event){javascript:fncAjaxSearch('wsDatabase','..\\AjaxBrowses\\PartBrowse.asp',''+$(this).attr("id")+'',''+$(this).attr("id")+'List','fncPreAjaxPart','fncPostAjaxPart');})
        .each(function(){$(this).after('<div id="'+$(this).attr("id")+'List" class="AjaxSuggest"></div>');});
```

After reading the 'Learning Jquery' book, it says about binding events to variable.  Is this correct, and if so, what would be the best wat to alter my code above to dynamically create variable names and then bind the events to these.

Thanks.

Comment: how many times does .PartNo exist in the DOM?

Comment: Only once.  Each id is unique, so I select by the class type.

Comment: I've noticed by using task manager, and seeing the memory usage of IE increase as I hyperlink around the intranet.  If I go back to the home page, the memory doesn't drop down - ever.....

Answer (score 0):

After further investigation, it looks like the problem is a generic problem with IE and not being caused by jquery.